# How to make ClipPlanes only affect one of the 3D objects?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

In order to show the maximum hemisphere inscribed to a unit cuboid, I use the following code:

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[
  30 - 12 Sqrt[6] + x (-6 + 2 Sqrt[6] + x) + y (-6 + 2 Sqrt[6] + y) + 
    z (-6 + 2 Sqrt[6] + z) == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Classic", 
  ClipPlanes -> -{1, 1, 1, 3 (Sqrt[6] - 3)}, 
  ClipPlanesStyle -> {Opacity[.5]}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Ball[{1, 4 - 3 Sqrt[3/2], 4 - 3 Sqrt[3/2]}, .1]}, 
  Boxed -> False], 
 Graphics3D[{Green, 
   Sphere[{5 - 2 Sqrt[6], 2 - Sqrt[3/2], 2 - Sqrt[3/2]}, .1]}, 
  Boxed -> False]
 ]
```

[image]

I add two `sphere` /`ball` 3D objects in order to indicate the edge of the hemisphere. But I don't want the balls being clipped too.

How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ClipPlanes` can be limited to specific primitives.  In this case the easiest way is probably to pass them in as part of the contour style:

```
Show[
    ContourPlot3D[
        30 - 12 Sqrt[6] + x (-6 + 2 Sqrt[6] + x) + y (-6 + 2 Sqrt[6] + y) + 
        z (-6 + 2 Sqrt[6] + z) == 0, {x, 0, 1.1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
        Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "Classic", BoundaryStyle -> None,
        ContourStyle -> Directive[{
            (* coerce to floating point because of, um, reasons *)
            ClipPlanes -> -{1, 1, 1, 3 (Sqrt[6] - 3.)}, 
            ClipPlanesStyle -> {Opacity[.5]}
            }]
        ], 
    Graphics3D[{Red, Ball[{1, 4 - 3 Sqrt[3/2], 4 - 3 Sqrt[3/2]}, .1]}, 
        Boxed -> False], 
    Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[{5 - 2 Sqrt[6], 2 - Sqrt[3/2], 2 - Sqrt[3/2]}, .1]}, 
        Boxed -> False]
]
```

[image]

Comment: I am surprised that   the `coercing to floating point` is very critical, or the `ClipPlane` will not work. How do you know that? do you have any explanation? thank you, it works now.

Comment: Well, I didn't know it at first.  I tried it as an exact number, and it didn't behave as I expected. Then I tried a simpler clip plane, and it did.  So really, just the usual process for figuring out how to get something to work.